# My repository is using CI/CD, but I have this error. How can I fix it?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, github-actions, cicd

I have a project and have made changes to a remote branch. My repository has CI/CD implemented, but when GitHub Actions are performing the build, this error occurs:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
> postcss src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o src/assets/css/app.css

Creating an optimized production build...

Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.

Failed to compile.

chunk 1 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/components/layout/modules/nav-item.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/components/UI/modules/card.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) ,

chunk 1 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/components/UI/modules/backdrop.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/components/UI/modules/card.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) ,

chunk 1 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/components/UI/modules/card.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/components/layout/modules/affiliate-card.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) 
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) ,


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I fix it? I appreciate any kind of help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `scripts` in `package.json` to:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

If you notice clearly, I have changed the `build` script to include `CI=false`. This is because, the build process is treating your warnings as errors and the build fails. Setting `CI=false` would mean that your build won't fail if warnings are present.